# How to write similar code to urllib.request.openurl in Python

Tags: python

I want to get the result just like urllib.request.openurl(url)

but I can't use the urllib nor any library

I have to write GET request on my own

but simple GET request like `b'GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\n\r\n'` does not return the html doc

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: What is your current code?

Comment: You can always copy the source code of the library.

Answer (score 1):

What version of python are you running? 2.7 or 3.x?

```
pip install requests
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.com/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
```

python for beginners: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python